# Wordpress and Google Analytics Events

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, dom-events, contact-form

I want to track some actions in Google Analytics but I can't get it working.

I tried it with Contact Forms (Wordpress). At the additional settings I just wrote:

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'Formular-Beratung', 'sent');"
```

but it does not work. I installed the Google tag assistant, but I cant see any event (not even in the live view at Google Analytics).

Next:
There is a live chat (snapengage). Here you can also track events. For this I implemented the code

```
var seAgent;
SnapABug.setCallback('StartChat', function (email, msg, type) {
    seAgent = agent;
    ga('send','event','SnapEngage', 'hasChatted', email);
});
```

I got this from there official site: [see here](https://developer.snapengage.com/javascript-api/javascript-events/)

This code should send an event to Google, when someone is sending a message in the chat), but nothing happens.

It seems like the whole site does not send ANY events to Google.

[This](http://coolperfect.de/) is the site I am talking about. Please could anybody have a look at this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you initialize the tracker object before you call the `ga()` method. You do this by placing this code at the top of the source code of your page (right after the `<body>` element:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
</script>
```

Make sure to replace the UA-XXXXXXX-Y with your own property ID.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I thinks this is already placed above the other codes.

Frist code on the site is: Google Analytics
Second: Facebook Pixel
Third: SnapEngage

You can see the codes at the site.
Or do you mean something different?

Comment: This (https://contactform7.com/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/) states the on_sent_ok is no longer the recommended method. Can you try the approach they specify in that article?

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your support! :)

But i don`t think this is the problem. It says: "This function is scheduled to be abolished by the end of 2017." For me this means - actually this should work. Further - contactform 7 is only one problem. Also snapengage is not firing any events. I think there is something generally blocking google analytics from triggering events. But i really don´t now what :(

Comment: New site - same problem. Could you guys please have a look right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170043/contact-form-7-google-analytics-tracking I tried the new DOM events and this doesn´t work either.

I am getting crazy. Thank you so much.