# Contact form 7 - Google Analytics Tracking

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form-7, event-tracking

I`m trying to track submitted contact forms in google analytics with contact form 7. 
I tried the following:

1. I placed the code

   `on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit');"`

in the additional settings. Does not work. This method is supported until the end of 2017. The new method is "DOM events", so...

2. ...I tried it with DOM events. I placed the code

   `<script>
   document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
       ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit');
   }, false );
   </script>`

in the head of the template. Also, does not work.

3. I also tried a WordPress plugin "Contact Form 7 Google Analytics" and this doesn´t work either. No matter which way I tried: The site doesn´t execute the line:

   `ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit');`

No event appears in the live view of google analytics.
I had this problem a few months ago ([Wordpress and Google Analytics Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957553/wordpress-and-google-analytics-events)) but this is a new site and i think it`s the same problem. There must be reason?

You can find the new site I am talking about [here](http://b2b.coolperfect.de/kontakt/).

I am really happy about any help. Thank you!

Edit: New hint:
After submitting a form there is no "thank you message". Nothing happens an the url changes to http://page.xyz/kontakt/#wpcf7-f4-p18-o1
I think this is not normal?

Comment: Have you checked your version of Google Analytics? The custom event will need to be different for analytics.js or ga.js
Also, try adding on_sent_ok: "console.log('test');" and check console after submission to test if it's an issue with CF7

Answer (score 0):

How did you set up event in google analytics? Maybe you need to pass a value in ga function.

[image]

If you set a value to 0 here and its "Greater than" selected, then you have to pass a value of '1' in ga send function.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. In my understanding I don`t have to set up this in google analytics. I think you are talking about "goals" I can set up in google analytics. This would be the next step for me but before i have to see that events are working.

Comment: You must create a goal, to see event working in google analytics side. I always setup goal, then create even script in website and on sending the event i check the analytics page for changes :)

Comment: Thank you. Tried it but this is also not working. For my other Wordpress pages events also work out of the box - without setting sth. up in google analytics.

I found out something new: After submitting the form i don`t get the "thank you message" instead the page where i land ist called:
http://page.xyz/kontakt/#wpcf7-f4-p18-o1
I think this is nor normal? Other pages dont do this. Maybe this is a hint?

Comment: I think you have a problem with CF7 plugin and ajax. try installing earlier version of CF7 and see if thats the problem.

Comment: Got it:
wp_header and wp_footer were not implemented in the theme. Jesus Christ - it works - finally. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the Contact Form 7 Google Analytics Intelligence plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-intelligence. It automates the whole process including goal creation.